# Deleting the last element of an array and then return the rest of the array

Tags: php

Sorry friends it might be something basic but i couldn't figure it out

i have an array

```
$_POST = array("name"=>"John","fname"=>"Anderson","submit"=>"submit");
```

what i want is to return the $_POST array after deleting the last element `"submit" => "submit"`

I know this can be done by simply unset the submit but i want it to be dynamically.

I tried doing

```
$_POST = array_pop($_POST);
print_r($_POST);
```

But it is returing me "submit" word only. What i want it should return

```
array("name"=>"John","fname"=>"Anderson");
```

Updated Part:

```
public function insertRow($table,$_post){
        $_post = (array_pop($_post));
        print_r($_post);
    }

$Connection->insertRow("users",array("name"=>"raheel","fname"=>"masood","submit"=>"submit"));
```

In the above function the $_post is returning me submit only

Comment: Simple.  Don't `name` your submit button.  This way that unwanted value will not be in `$_POST`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `array_pop` function modifies the array in place; it returns what was popped, not the array after the pop.  So don't assign the return value back to `$_POST`.

If you want to get all but the last element of `$_POST` *without* actually modifying `$_POST` itself, you can use `array_slice`:

```
$_POST_minus_last = array_slice($_POST, 0, -1);
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php):

> mixed `array_pop` ( array *&$array* )
>
> `array_pop()` pops and returns the last value of the array, shortening the array by one element. If `array` is 
>   empty (or is not an array), `NULL` will be returned. Will additionally produce a Warning when called on a non-
>   array.
>
> Note: This function will `reset()` the array pointer of the input array after use.

so:

```
$popdValue = array_pop($_POST); // no assignment to $_POST
echo $popdValue; // last element removed from $_POST
print_r($_POST); // remaining $_POST
```

Comment: so how would i return the rest of array elements after it popped out the last element?

Comment: so thats what i m doing i m doing print_r($_POST) but it showing me submit only

Comment: Let me update my question first...some thing else is happening wrong

Comment: You're setting `$_POST = array_pop($_POST);` Don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can also make use of **`array_splice()`**

```
<?php
$arr = array("name"=>"John","fname"=>"Anderson","submit"=>"submit");
array_splice($arr,2);
print_r($arr);
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Array ( [name] => John [fname] => Anderson )
```

Answer (score -1):

Because `array_pop` returns the element that was popped. Not the rest of the array.

```
array_pop($_POST);
print_r($_POST);
```

Comment: Want to explain the downvote? This is what OP asked for. Though its not really clear why he wouldn't use `unset`